# Why Android show "Network may be monitored" with Nordvpn?

Tags: vpn

According the customer service,  it is a feature. However,  I would like to understand why Android cannot separate Vpn traffic from real monitoring of attackers.

Fig. 1 Text *Network may be monitored* on the screen

[image]

OS: Oxygen OS 3.1
Phone: One plus 2

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. What does the VPN have to do with monitoring of attackers? The notification is trying to tell you that whoever owns the VPN service can potentially see your network traffic (which is absolutely true).

Comment: @eldarerathis It seems you understand my question. Please, see the body for the figure of the case.

Comment: Android shows that for _any_ VPN service you use, be it an external app or not. It's just a mandatory warning.

Comment: @AndyYan Yes. The point of this thread is to understand why. Why it cannot exclude your VPN from other uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background**

This is a known feature  which occurs when a *Installing a private CA certificate for use with vpn or private web site encryption and or authentication*  or *using self signed certificates*, figuring in bug reports:

- [Issue 62076: "network may be monitored"](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62076)
- [Issue 82036: Self signed certificates cause  "network may be monitored" warning](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82036)

Common refrain of user complaints is that this warning is (amongst others)

- Of no real use
- Inconvenience to corporates
- Impractical to expect users to get  Google approved CA certificates for their uses

Google engineer has clarified in the first source (post 8) :

> The "User" portion of the trusted credential store is non-system CA certificates that have been installed and are trusted by the browser and other things that use the system Trusted Certificate Store. **This warning is about protecting the user of the device**

(Emphasis supplied)

And provides an example  of how  user security can be breached

---

Coming to your question

> Why Android cannot separate Vpn traffic from real monitoring of attackers.

Android cannot. *Period.*

Whether it is VPN or monitoring by attackers. As explained, it is only providing a **warning** that your network traffic can be monitored if you continue to use VPN / apps / self signed CA.

If you want the OS capability to deal with this kind of protection, then it *seems* to exist in the [world's costliest Android phone - Solarin](https://www.sirinlabs.com/)

Comment: Very nice phone! It has some nice features, existing only in a few models at the moment. I need to get one similar one day. How did you find the company? Is there any reviews about their phone in practice?

Comment: Googling *sirin labs + previews*, you get much better results. It is very impressive phone. I would like to get more analysis about their security tweaks of Snapdragon 820 cpu and their power management - - I think the price does not matter, since it is only such a phone in the market, offering us a possibility to compare our own phones to it and develop better ones. - - I contacted them about those things.

Comment: Was wondering,  since there had been no revert